# Change ImageIcon during

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I have two questions:

1. I'm creating a simple memory game that save a random sequence and expect the same input from player, and i'm trying to change an `JButton` `ImageIcon` when clicked to a brighter version of the `img1` using the `setIcon()` but nothing  change during run-time.

   ```
   private final JButton btnImg1 = new JButton("");
   ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\vide\\Desktop\\img1.png");
   ImageIcon img1_b = new  ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\vide\\Desktop\\img1_b.png");

   try {
        btnImg1.setIcon(img1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        btnImg1.setIcon(img1_b);
    }
   ```
2. I made 2 `int` `List`s to save the inputs and the random sequence, cause of the dynamic size:

   ```
   List<Integer> seqAlea =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
   List<Integer> seqInsere =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int placar = 0;

   Random geraNumero = new Random();

   public void comecaJogo(){

       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           int numero = geraNumero.nextInt(4) + 1;             
           seqAlea.add(i, numero);
       }
   }
   ```

There is a better way to do it?

Comment: To change icon of button when click it, add `btnImg1.setIcon(img1_b);` to your buttons action listener.

Comment: *Never* sleep in the event dispatch thread. Nothing gets drawn while the EDT is blocked. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead when you want a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, NEVER use a sleep in your main thread if you don't mean to block it, this will make your application wait until the sleep is over, thus "blocking" your main thread.

1. For your first question, this code would solve:

   ```
   // Assuming that your image will be within your package
   final URL resource = getClass().getResource("/com/mypackage/myimage.png");

   final JButton btn = new JButton("My Button");
   final Image image = ImageIO.read(resource);
   final ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(image);

   btn.setIcon(defaultIcon);
   btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           try {
               //This will do the trick to brighten your image
               Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

               // Here we're creating a white color with 50% of alpha transparency
               g2.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 50));
               // Fill the entire image with the new color
               g2.fillRect(0, 0, defaultIcon.getIconWidth(), defaultIcon.getIconHeight());
               g2.dispose();
               btnBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               /*Although this is a bad practice, my point here is not 
                * to explain exceptions. 
                * But it's a good practice to always capture as many exceptions as you can
               */
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Well, you don't actually NEED to explicitely inform in which position you're adding the element, specially if it's a sequence. Arraylists don't sort items.

Comment: So just to clarify: Should I import the same image in "Image image" and "ImageIcon defaultIcon" and switch between them ?

Comment: It's not like you're switching them. We have an object, let's use it. We are actually using the `Graphics` from `Image` to create and manipulate its colors, to brighten it, then we create a `new ImageIcon` with it.
Let's assume you have to change the color of, I don't know, 1000 images. You, for sure, don't want to add more 1000 bright versions of those images, right? That's the way to go to avoid adding more images to your program.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the Graphics2 object, g2, when done using it. 1+ up-vote for a nice answer. Myself, I'd avoid creating icons as the program is running though and try to create them all at start up (if memory constraints allow).

Comment: And to solve his time delay issue, he will need to use a Swing Timer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for your feedback! I'll fix and add the `g2.dispose()`. I agree with you about creating icons at startup. 
About the time delay, I don't really know why 'twas there, don't know if there's a reason, but ,yes, Swing Timer is a great solution!

Comment: Guys, thanks for the great answers! But I'm facing another issue, when using the ImageIO.read(resource), I face the unhandle exception type IOException, even putting each ImageIO.read inside a try/catch. Any tips? Thanks :)

Comment: Did find the solution, put it inside the constructor method ^^, btw, what should always be inside the constructor, the instance of the buttons, or only the calls and the instance outside? Thanks!!